# How to add values to empty map in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am struggling on adding map inside empty list like below, How can I add map one by one to empty list ?

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data =[];

//every time I click I want to add map inside above data

//expected output finally look like 
data = [
{'title': 'Food', 'price':15,'qty':2},
{'title': 'pen', 'price':10,'qty':3},// added one by one
{'title': 'pc', 'price':13,'qty':1},
]
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

```
final data = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];

data.add({'title': 'Food', 'price':15,'qty':2})
```

...
And so on

Comment: how to remove based on id  or should I include all object like ```data.remove({'title':'Food', 'price':15, 'qty':2})``` ?